# How can I modify the margins when I plot map with cartopy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I use cartopy(following code) to draw world maps. I have set as `ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])`. However, the output maps always show large margins over the frames. I want to show the map as full screen or full-size of images.
How to set the margins of the cartopy plotting?

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
ax.outline_patch.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: output img here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two axes.

1. `ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])` This is the axes that sits tight on the figure
2. `ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())` this is the axes that shows the world map, but has the usual margins.

You may of course decide for one of those and remove the other, e.g.

```
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

This will create an axes which sits tight at **one side of the figure**. The reason is that the map has a fixed aspect ratio and which is not the same as the one of the figure.

So to have the axes tight **along both sides of the figure**, you need to set the figure size as well. The aspect of the world map is 0.5, because it goes 360 units in horizontal and 180 units in vertical direction. Hence the figure width needs to be twice as large as the figure heigt. E.g.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3.5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get it. The error is Two Axes I made. I added `plt.tight_layout(pad=0)` just now to force the image to stretch to full size, in fact, it worked on the second axes.